# Location + mapview - ComponentWillMount resolves before render does? React Native | Expo

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, location, expo

I can sometimes get the right location, most of the time before the state updates, render() calls up fetching nulled states.

i have tried adding async + await conditions but to no avail. How can i make sure map is rendered once the location data has been set to the states.

here's the code.

so again, may be i could somewhere place nexttick() or so to ensure the updated states are used to render?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Platform,Text,Image,View,StyleSheet,Dimensions} from "react-native";
import { MapView, Constants, Location, Permissions } from "expo";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height;
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width;
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

export default class ComplaintScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null,
    
    positionState: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      latitudeDelta: 0,
      longitudeDelta: 0
    },

    markerPosition: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0
    }
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === "android" && !Constants.isDevice) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage:
          "Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!"
      });
    } else {
      await this._getLocationAsync();
    }
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "Permission to access location was denied"
      });
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync(
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout:5000, maxiumumAge: 10000
      });
    this.setState({ location });
    var lat = parseFloat(location.coords.latitude);
    var long = parseFloat(location.coords.longitude);

   
    var region = {
      latitude: lat,
      longitude: long,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
    };
     this.setState({ positionState: region });
     this.setState({ markerPosition: region });
  };


 render() {
    return (
      console.log(this.state.positionState),
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <MapView style={Styles.map} initialRegion={this.state.positionState}>
          <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.markerPosition}>
            <View style={Styles.radius}>
              <View style={Styles.marker} />
            </View>
          </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
 {some styles were here removed to keep the post short}
});
```

Comment: why can't you do call `this._getLocationAsync();` in componentDidMount?

Comment: i'm a little unsure on that, but wont this be called after that component is rendered?
if the component is rendered, this particular function would run afterwards giving me the same results?

Comment: try to put `await` before `this.setState`

Comment: let me try that...

Comment: nope! i think i have to add some loading screen or such in order to load mapview with the updated coordinates...componentWillMount() should although update states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did something like adding an activity loader then checking if the coords have updated, only then display the map. works for now, if there's a better approach, would love it.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import { MapView, Constants, Location, Permissions } from "expo";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height;
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width;
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

export default class ComplaintScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "New Complaint",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#010245",
      paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
      height: 60 + Constants.statusBarHeight
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerRight: (
      <Image
        source={require("../assets/img/header/hr.png")}
        style={{ justifyContent: "center", padding: 3, margin: 3 }}
      />
    )
  };

  state = {
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null,
    loading: true, 
    loadingMap:false,
    positionState: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      latitudeDelta: 0,
      longitudeDelta: 0
    },

    markerPosition: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0
    }
  };
  
  async componentWillMount() {
    Location.setApiKey('AIzaSyAHSZHScQK-AslKB8QSIyDfqwGc2adFaUM');
    if (Platform.OS === "android" && !Constants.isDevice) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage:
          "Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!"
      });
    } else {
      await this._getLocationAsync();
    }
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "Permission to access location was denied"
      });
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync(
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout:5000, maxiumumAge: 10000
      });
    this.setState({ location });
    var lat = parseFloat(location.coords.latitude);
    var long = parseFloat(location.coords.longitude);

   
    var region = {
      latitude: lat,
      longitude: long,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
    };
      this.setState({ positionState: region });
      this.setState({ markerPosition: region });
  };

componentDidUpdate(){
  if (this.state.positionState.latitude!=='0'){
  this.state.loadingMap = true; 
  this.state.loading = false;
  }  
}
 render() {
    return (
      console.log(this.state.positionState),
      
      <View style={Styles.container}>
      {this.state.loadingMap &&
        <MapView style={Styles.map} initialRegion={this.state.positionState}>
          <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.markerPosition}>
            <View style={Styles.radius}>
              <View style={Styles.marker} />
            </View>
          </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>
      }
        {this.state.loading &&
          <View style={Styles.loading}>
            <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
          </View>
      } 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  radius: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 50 / 2,
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.1)",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "rgba(0, 112, 255, 0.3)",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  marker: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20 / 2,
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: "#007AFF"
  },

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },

  map: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  loading: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may also want to call the react-maps-native animateToRegion by using the reference of the MapView.

This is my suggested alternative that works for my project:

```
_getLocationAsync = async()=> {
let {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
if(status!=='granted'){
  this.setState({errorMessage:"Permissions not granted."})
}
let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
this.map.animateToRegion({
    latitude: location.coords.latitude,
    longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}, 200)}
```

Checkout the reference here: 
[MapView API](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)